# get all handles of a window

Tags: c#, handles

Im looking for a way to get all handles in a specified window,
of every button and everything.
I tried with [EnumDesktopWindows](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/EnumDesktopWindows.html) but it doesnt enum every handle, only the window handles.

Answer (score 2):

```
  public Form1()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     List<IntPtr> handles = GetHandles(this.Controls);
  }

  public List<IntPtr> GetHandles(Control.ControlCollection inControls)
  {
     List<IntPtr> list_of_handles = new List<IntPtr>();
     if(inControls != null)
     {
        foreach (Control c in inControls)
        {
           list_of_handles.Add(c.Handle);
           list_of_handles.AddRange(GetHandles(c.Controls));
        }
     }
     return list_of_handles;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think he is trying to get the handles of another window, not his window